# Compile winform .Net application to native binary file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, x86, native

I'm looking for a way to compile my C# winforms application into a one native PE (Portable Executable) file.

I've read a lot and found that the .Net Native is not compatible with winforms, and there are some other ways including the overhead of compiling into dlls.

I wonder if there is such **a tool that creates a binary file out of the box for .Net winforms applications**.

Comment: Then you have to wait till it supports WinForms or you write your own.